# OpenMP Support in Xcode 5 and later

Tags: xcode, openmp

I have a proprietary library (>150,000 lines) of quantum mechanics C++ code that relies on OpenMP for parallisation. This code used to compile fine with Xcode 4.6 and its' *real* GCC compiler, but the LLVM compiler that ships with Xcode 5 doesn't seem to support OpenMP. My code is developed on a Mac but needs to be portable to non-Apple hardware such as massively parallel supercomputers, so re-writing the code is not an option. Does anyone know of a suitable compiler that can be used? Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to support OpenMP"? Does it really only *seem* that way or do you get actual error messages you could post here? And if Xcode 5 really doesn't work with the project are there any reasons why you can't continue to use Xcode 4.6?

Comment: I can find no option in the project settings to 'enable openMP support' which had been present in earlier versions of Xcode. I get a warning:/Users/richard/Develop/QMLib/QMLib.xcodeproj Invalid C/C++ compiler in target QMLib: com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42

Comment: I guess I have the same problem since I upgraded to Lion Mavericks and XCode 5. I was using eclipse with C projects which was compiling fine under Mountain Lion and XCode 4.6. Now when I'm compiling I have the error 'fatal error: 'omp.h' file not found'. Still looking for a solution. Maybe have a look to http://hpc.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 2):

I come back from my comment as I tested hpc.sourceforge.net and it is working like a charm for me.

Simply untar the archive as explained:

```
sudo tar -xvf gcc-4.8-bin.tar -C /
```

Update your .profile to use by default the hpc compiled version of gcc if you want.

Compile your program with option -fopenmp then link it with option -lgomp.

Answer (score 1):

"Does anyone know of a suitable compiler that can be used?"

The Intel compilers on MacOS support OpenMP, as they do on other platforms.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-software-development-products-for-mac-os-x

Of course, they cost money, but they may be worth it.

(Full disclosure: I work for Intel on the OpenMP runtime used by the compiler)

Answer (score 0):

See [Clang + OpenMP Setup in Xcode](http://antonmenshov.com/2017/09/09/clang-openmp-setup-in-xcode/). The steps are basically:

1. Install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh).
2. Install  llvm with `brew install llvm`.
3. “Build Settings” and then “Editor” » “Add Build Setting” » “Add User-Defined Setting” with key of `CC` and value of `/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang`.
4. Search for “Enable Modules” and turn that off.
5. Add `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib` to “Library Search Paths”.
6. Add `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/clang/7.0.1/include` to “Header Search Paths”. (The version number may vary based upon your installation.)
7. Add `-fopenmp` compilation flag to “Other C Flags”.
8. Turn off “Enable Index-While-Building Functionality”.
9. Add `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/libiomp5.dylib` to “Build Phases” » “Link Binary with Libraries”.