# How to app support OpenMP in XCode 7

Tags: c++, xcode, gcc, compilation, openmp

It was "Enable OpenMP support" checkbox in XCode 4.6, but in XCode 7 there is no such option. How I can do this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082102/1271826

Answer (score 1):

Apple's Developer Tools have dropped support for OpenMP. On OS X, the easiest way to get OpenMP support is to install gcc or clang-omp via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help