# gcc compile, getting "clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'"

Tags: gcc, openmp, macos-mojave

I am running the command

```
gcc -o openmptest -fopenmp openmptest.c
```

however am getting the error:

```
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
```

I am running this on Mac Mojave. In addition I am using VS code which is telling me

cannot open source file "omp.h"

for my include statement.

Comment: I can’t comment on VS Code, but I’ve been writing OpenMP programs on Mojave using Xcode following the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082102/1271826

Comment: Look at your symbolic links. gcc shouldn't invoke LLVM...

Comment: What is a better way to compile the c file?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could work if you install libomp by

brew install libomp

and then,

clang -Xpreprocessor -fopenmp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lomp  openmptest.c -o main

This should work, I was having the same issue and and managed to compile my code by using the above.