# clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'. Change default compiler?

Tags: macos, gcc, cmake, clang

I am on a Mac but I am not a Mac user. I need to run a `make` command (actually `make makewisdom`) to compile a software, but my compiler does not recognize some commands:

```
$ make makewisdom
gcc -I/Users/username/presto/include -I/opt/local/include/glib-2.0 -I/opt/local/lib/glib-2.0/include -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I -I/opt/local/include -DUSEFFTW -DUSEMMAP -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -Wall -W -fPIC -O3 -ffast-math -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-but-set-parameter -fopenmp -o makewisdom makewisdom.c -L/opt/local/lib -lfftw3f

clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
clang: error: unsupported option '-fopenmp'
make: *** [makewisdom] Error 1
```

I know the problem is with `clang`. I am reading lots of discussions (such [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43555410/enable-openmp-support-in-clang-in-mac-os-x-sierra-mojave) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36211018/clang-error-errorunsupported-option-fopenmp-on-mac-osx-el-capitan-buildin), and more), and trying to workaround the problem, but no luck yet. It maybe that I just need to set a different default compiler? (to, for example, `gcc`, whatever is the version I have installed):

```
$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Comment: How does `cmake` tag relate to the problem? Note, that `make` and `cmake` are quite different things.

Comment: I am not expert on this, but I found it related through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54715120/2107030).

Comment: How is that not clear? There is an error and I want to get rid of. If changing the compiler is a solution I'd like to be guided to do so because I have tried and did not succeeded. If it makes you feel better I can remove the `cmake` tag.

Comment: E.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36211162/3440745) describes how to change the compiler. "I have tried and did not succeeded." - Please, describe (in the question post) what **exactly** have you tried and what have you got on that attempt.

Comment: I have copied and pasted the new env variables from those answers, but probably something in the path/compiler is different. What is my default compiler? What other compilers I have installed? How do I redefine those variables for my system? This is where I need help

Comment: You still haven't describe what **exactly** you are doing, so it is hard to guess what you are doing wrong... It could be that your Makefile (which you don't show to us) use **hardcoded** `gcc` as a compiler and doesn't refer to `CC` or `CXX` variables. So for use "real" `gcc` compiler you may execute the command line `gcc -I/Users/username/presto/include ...` with "gcc" replaced with that real gcc compiler. Or you may follow [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19535422/os-x-10-9-gcc-links-to-clang) for make `gcc` points to the real gcc compiler.

Comment: There is no make file in the directory where I call the `make makewisdom`, I suppose it will be created by the `make makewisdom` command. I am just blindly following some instructions to install a software, I do not know much about compilers, make, gcc, etc.

Comment: "I am just blindly following some instructions to install a software, I do not know much about compilers, make, gcc, etc." - And we know a little about your environment and scripts (like Makefile). How do you expect us to help you in this situation?

Comment: Experts can ask me the right questions to know the right answers. Most often, a few terminal commands can give all information you need. I will then edit the question to add relevant information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenMP Support in Xcode 5 and later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19208281/openmp-support-in-xcode-5-and-later)

Comment: @l'L'l, please can you show me how that can help me/which answer should I follow. From a first glance it does not really help (for example, I do not know to what "build settings" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55082102/2107030) refers to), also there is no accepted answer.

Comment: @Py-ser: The problem is the compiler version you are using. You’ll want to install a version of clang that supports `OpenMP`. I’m on mobile at the moment, so can’t tell you exactly which one you would need. Usually you can install an alternate version via `MacPorts` or `Homebrew` so that it doesn’t mess with the default Apple one.

Comment: @l'L'l, thank you. A link with some instructions would be great: I do not want to messy up things more than what they already are.

Comment: Use the `-Xpreprocessor` Flag to get apple clang to recognize openmp

Comment: @RichardBarber, could you write the entire command? Maybe you can also post an answer with that.

Comment: @Py-ser try to add on the flag with an environment variable for instance, `CFLAGS="-Xpreprocessor" make makewisdom`

Comment: @RichardBarber, it does not change a thing.

Comment: @Py-ser, did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am struggling right now with the same issue.

Comment: @Phyast10, nope...

Comment: hmm, is there a workaround about it? I am also using it in context of Presto. Please tag me, if you find a solution. I will look around and do the same.